# rails migration columns name with _id suffix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

Want to do rails migration but i want the column name to be something like external_id but I don't want to any model with external . i think rails by default , whenever sees _id as suffix it looks for foreign key association and if it doesn't exist migration is canceled.
what's the solution for that. I have

```
def self.up
    create_table :external_mappings do |t|
      t.string :external_name
      t.integer :external_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Thanks for your help

---

when i make it  t.integer :externalId migration works. that make me think external_id is looking for foreiegn key reference, is there any way we can suppress foriegn key reference. I am using rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

You can give to any column a `_id` name and reference foreign keys without the `_id` also, so feel free to continue. It is just a convention on which Rails relies to target the `model-name_id`, but with no trouble it can be defined differently.

Answer (score 0):

No, rails does not cancel any migration due non existent model.

Comment: when i do  t.integer :external_id

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the original poster created the new model using scaffolding and the "references" type. If that is the case, the migration would have failed during it's attempt to creating the foreign key.

Otherwise, if it's just an integer, there is nothing wrong with adding an _id to the end of an otherwise acceptable column name.